# Problem with numerical solution of a system of ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, physics, nonlinear

#### Background

Good evening, I have a big problem with num. solution **NDSolve** of differential equation.
To start with, the model:

There is a fast-moving rope in closed path. Where

$T$ is tension,

$a$ is angle beetwen rope and horizontal plane,

$s$ is curvilinear coordinates $[0,1]$ ($0$ - the beginning of the rope, $1$ - the ending of the rope).

$Dr$ drag coefficient

$W$  weight coefficient

And it gives the differential equations for $T$, $a$ and $s$.

$$\frac{d}{ds}(T(s)\sin\alpha(s))=W+Dr\sin\alpha(s) $$

$$\frac{d}{ds}(T(s)\cos\alpha(s))=Dr\cos\alpha(s) $$

```
D[T[s] Sin[a[s]], s] == W + Dr Sin[a[s]], 
D[T[s] Cos[a[s]], s] == Dr Cos[a[s]],
```

Moreover, boundary conditions comes from equation for beginning and ending of the rope. $x[0] = x[1] = 0, y[0] = y[1] = 0$, where $x[s]$, $y[s]$ are coordinates of point on the rope with curve distance to beginning $s$. It means, that ending and beginning of the rope are in the same place.
Differential equations for coodinates $x[s],y[s]$ are quite easy.

$$\frac{dy(s)}{ds}=\frac{\tan \alpha(s)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 \alpha(s)}}   $$

$$\frac{dx(s)}{ds}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 \alpha(s)}}   $$

```
(Tan[a[s]])/Sqrt[1 + Tan[a[s]]^2] == D[y[s], s],
1/Sqrt[1 + Tan[a[s]]^2] == D[x[s], s],
x[0] == 0,
y[0] == 0,
x[1] == ϵ,
y[1] == ϵ
```

I've solved it, but solution is unreal and contradicts boundary conditions.
But *Mathematica*'s solution in ParametricPlot looks like this:

[image: **Fig.1** Obtained soltion]

**Fig.1** Obtained soltion

The rope should be closed, but it's not. And it should look like that:

[image: **Fig.2** Shape of rope in dependence of Dr/W]

**Fig.2** Shape of rope in dependence of $\frac{Dr}{W}$

Please, help. The final code:

```
x[s] =.
y[s] =.
NumSol = Block[{\[Epsilon] = $MachineEpsilon},
  With[{Dr = 9.9, W = 8},
   NDSolve[{
     D[T[s] Sin[a[s]], s] == W + Dr Sin[a[s]],
     D[T[s] Cos[a[s]], s] == Dr Cos[a[s]],
     (Tan[a[s]])/Sqrt[1 + Tan[a[s]]^2] == D[y[s], s],
     1/Sqrt[1 + Tan[a[s]]^2] == D[x[s], s],
     x[\[Epsilon]] == 0,
     y[\[Epsilon]] == 0,
     x[1 - \[Epsilon]] == \[Epsilon],
     y[1 - \[Epsilon]] == \[Epsilon]
     },
    {T, a, x, y}, {s, \[Epsilon], 1 - \[Epsilon]},
    Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", "NonstiffTest" -> False}]]]

ParametricPlot[{x[s], y[s]} /. NumSol // Evaluate, {s, 0, 1},
 PlotRange -> Automatic,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}
 ]
```

Comment: Where did you get this closed loop picture?

Comment: "$a$ is angle beetwen rope and gorizontal plane. " So, the range of $a$ is not $(-\frac\pi 2,\frac\pi 2)$?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I get this picture from this article: [
Propelled Strings: Rising from Friction](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.123.144501). Author's of the aricle solved the same problem and got this picture, I'm trying to get it too.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, $a$ must be in this range.

Comment: @danyesss The article discusses the analytical solution for $T, \alpha$. Help you find this solution?

Comment: Then the equation is a bit strange, $y'(s)$ jumps when $a$ crosses $\frac \pi 2$?

Comment: @xzczd How can I add the range of $a$ in **NDSolve**?

Comment: You can not. The range of `a` is determined by the property of the ODE system. `WhenEvent` can be used of course, but that's another story.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer has been significantly revised**

Begin by obtaining symbolic solutions for `T[s]` and `a[s]`.

```
sat = DSolveValue[{D[T[s] Sin[a[s]], s] == W + Dr Sin[a[s]], 
    D[T[s] Cos[a[s]], s] == Dr Cos[a[s]]}, {a[s], T[s]}, s]
```

but the result is a bit lengthy to reproduce here.  However, simpler expressions can be extracted from `sat` for `a[s]`

```
eqa = Simplify[sat[[1, 1]] /. C[1] -> W*C[1]] == 
    Simplify[sat[[1, 0, 1]][a[s]] /. Dr -> r*W]
(* s/C[1] + C[2] == ((Cos[a[s]/2] - Sin[a[s]/2])^(-1 - r) 
   (Cos[a[s]/2] + Sin[a[s]/2])^(-1 + r) (r - Sin[a[s]]))/(-1 + r^2) *)
```

where `r = Dr/W` has been introduced for compactness.  `T[s]`also can be obtained in terms of `a[s]`, although it is not needed for the computation below.

```
eqT = FullSimplify[sat[[2]] /. {sat[[1]] -> a[s], Dr -> r*W}]
(* C[1] Sec[a[s]] (Cos[a[s]/2] - Sin[a[s]/2])^(-r) (Cos[a[s]/2] + Sin[a[s]/2])^r *)
```

Analyzing `eqa`, we see that it is valid for `Real`C[_] only when `- Pi/2 < a[s] < Pi/2`.  But, based on the reference provided by the OP in a comment above, `- Pi/2 < a[s] < - 3 Pi/2` also is needed to solve the problem posed in the question.  The latter solution can be obtained by the substitution `a[s] -> Pi - a[s]`and renormalization of `C[1]`.  Combine the two.

```
eqaext = eqa[[1]] == Piecewise[{{eqa[[2]], a[s] > -Pi/2}, 
    {-Simplify[eqa[[2]] /. a[s] -> Pi - a[s]], a[s] < -Pi/2}}, 0]
(* s/C[1] + C[2] == Piecewise[{{((Cos[a[s]/2] - Sin[a[s]/2])^(-1 - r)*
   (Cos[a[s]/2] + Sin[a[s]/2])^(-1 + r)*(r - Sin[a[s]]))/(-1 + r^2), a[s] > -Pi/2}, 
   {-(((-Cos[a[s]/2] + Sin[a[s]/2])^(-1 - r)*(Cos[a[s]/2] + Sin[a[s]/2])^(-1 + r)*
   (r - Sin[a[s]]))/(-1 + r^2)), a[s] < -Pi/2}}, 0] *)
```

Note that the constants, `C[_]` may not be the same above and below `a[s] = - Pi/2`.  In fact, determining `C[_]` is the essence of the computation.  Here is a plot of `eqaext[[2]]` for `r = 9.9/8`, the value employed in the question.

```
ParametricPlot[{Last[eqaext /. {a[s] -> b, r -> 9.9/8}], b}, 
    {b, -3 Pi/2 + .01, Pi/2 - 0.01}, AxesLabel -> {"s/c1+c2", "a[s]"}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Black, Bold}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

A numerical expression for`a[s]` as a function of `Last[eqaext /. r -> 9.9/8}` can be obtain readily by

```
int = Interpolation[Table[{Re[Last[eqaext /. {a[s] -> b, r -> 9.9/8}]], b}, 
   {b, -3 Pi/2 + .0001, Pi/2 - .0001, .0001}]];
```

Surprizingly, this simple result is rather more robust than `InverseFunction` for the integrations that follow.

The specific problem that the code in the question attempts to address is equivalent to the respective `C[_]` being the same throughout `- 3 Pi/2 < a[s] < Pi/2`.  To determine these two constants, require that `{x[s], y[s]}` both are equal to zero at `s = 0` and `s = 1`, in other words that `fi[c1, c2] = {0,0}`, where

```
fi[c1_, c2_] := {NIntegrate[Cos[int[s/c1 + c2]], {s, 0, 1}], 
    NIntegrate[Sin[int[s/c1 + c2]], {s, 0, 1}]}
```

which is solved by

```
param = FindRoot[Quiet@fi[c10, c20], {{c10, -.7}, {c20, .6}}, 
    Evaluated -> False] // Values
Quiet[fi @@ %]
(* {-0.0909828, 5.49556} *)
(* {-1.13858*10^-16, 6.41848*10^-17} *)
```

Finally, a plot of `x[t]` and `y[t]` is obtained from

```
ps = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[s] == Cos[int[s/c1 + c2]], 
    y'[s] == Sin[int[s/c1 + c2]], x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0}, 
    {x[s], y[s]}, {s, 0, 1}, {c1, c2}];
ps @@ param;
ParametricPlot[%, {s, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
   ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Black, Bold}]
```

[image]

For completeness, `a[0]` is given by

```
int[param // Last]
(* 0.940888 *)
```

Let us turn now to reproducing a curve like those in the second figure in the question, for which `a[0]` is specified to be zero. Then, `C[_]` definitely are not the same above and below `a[s] = - Pi/2`. The four seemingly undetermined constants are reduced to two as follow.  At `s = 0`.

```
c2p = Last[eqaext /. {a[s] -> 0, r -> 9.9/8}]
(* 2.32873 *)
```

Next, note that `s` must be continuous at `a[s] = - Pi/2`, which in turn requires that `c1p*c2p = c1m*c2m`.  (Constants with names ending in `p` are for `- Pi/2 < a[s]`, and with `m` for `- Pi/2 > a[s]`.)  This reduces the number of free constants to two, as desired.  As before, determine them by requiring that `{x[s], y[s]}` both are equal to zero at `s = 0` and `s = 1`.

```
f0[c1p_, c1m_] := {NIntegrate[Piecewise[{{Cos[int[s/c1p + c2p]], s < -c1p*c2p}, 
    {Cos[int[s/c1m + c2p*c1p/c1m]], s > -c1p*c2p}}, 0], {s, 0, 1}], 
    NIntegrate[Piecewise[{{Sin[int[s/c1p + c2p]], s < -c1p*c2p}, 
    {Sin[int[s/c1m + c2p*c1p/c1m]], s > -c1p*c2p}}, 0], {s, 0, 1}]}

param = FindRoot[Quiet@f0[c1p0, c1m0], {{c1p0, -.1}, {c1m0, -.01}}, 
    Evaluated -> False] // Values
Quiet[f0 @@ %]
(* {-0.21471, -0.0133781} *)
(* {4.17224*10^-17, -9.19403*10^-17} *)
```

Finally, a plot of `x[t]` and `y[t]` is obtained from

```
ps0 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[s] == Piecewise[{{Cos[int[s/c1p + c2p]], 
    s < -c1p*c2p}, {Cos[int[s/c1m + c2p*c1p/c1m]], s > -c1p*c2p}}, 0], 
    y'[s] == Piecewise[{{Sin[int[s/c1p + c2p]], 
    s < -c1p*c2p}, {Sin[int[s/c1m + c2p*c1p/c1m]], s > -c1p*c2p}}, 0], 
    x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0}, {x[s], y[s]}, {s, 0, 1}, {c1p, c1m}];
ps0 @@ param;
ParametricPlot[%, {s, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Black, Bold}]
```

[image]

which fits well between the `r = 1` and `r = 1.5` curves in the second figure of the question.  Generating all the curves in the second figure would be straightforward.

Comment: This is a good algorithm (+1). But how to reproduce fig. 4 from the article https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.123.144501 ?

Comment: See Fig. 2 above with $Dr/W=0.2,0.5, 1, 1.5, 2.5, 5, 10$  and with $\alpha(0)=0$. And give me email for copy.

Comment: I sent you a copy.

Comment: @AlexTrounev  Thanks again for sharing the article.  Having read it, I now see how to proceed to obtain the second plot in the question, which I shall do tomorrow.