# How to combine NDSolve interpolating functions?

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, numerical-integration, interpolation

In the following working example

```
   s = NDSolve[{F'[r] == Sin[200*r]*x[r], x'[r] == F[r]*r^2, F[0] == 1, 
   x[0] == 11/10}, {F, x}, {r, 0, 1},


   Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta",
   WorkingPrecision -> 100, AccuracyGoal -> 31, PrecisionGoal -> 31, 
   InterpolationOrder -> All, MaxSteps -> 10^6];    


   FF = First[F /. s];
   xx = First[x /. s];
```

`NDSolve` returns two functions `F[r]` and `x[r]` with an accuracy of about `30 decimal digits`.

`x[r]` is a monotonically increasing function of `r` so in principle one can combine `F[r]` and `x[r]` to get  `F[x]`.

I know that `x[r]` is something like `{{r1,x1},{r2,x2},{r3,x3},...}` and `f[r]` is something like `{{r1,f1},{r2,f2},{r3,f3},...}`. So I have to get the second column from each function and construct something like `{{x1,f1},{x2,f2},{x3,f3},...}`.

Then if `fx[x]` is the new function it should be `fx[x[ro]] = FF[ro]` for any `ro` in `{0,1}`.

However I have not yet found out how.

My problem is that I have already some such interpolating `F[r]`'s and `x[r]`'s stored in `.txt` form with and accuracy of `30 decimal digits` and  I need `F[x]` with the **same accuracy**.

If there is no simple solution to this then I will have to start from the beggining.

**Alternative:** An alternative would be to find the inverse of `x[r]` i.e. `r[x]` and then define `fx[x_]:=F[r[x]]` when **preserving accuracy** at the same time. I have not yet managed this.

Comment: does `fx = First[F@*x /. s]` give what you need?

Comment: Well, it should be $fx(xx(r)) = FF(r)$ which I tried to verify with `N[ FF[1/2] - fx[xx[1/2]], 40]` i.e. with `r=1/2` but only got an `InterpolatingFunction::dmval` error. Probably I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @jheidk51  With `x[0] == 11/10`, no value of `x` falls within the domain of `F`, which is `{0,1}`.  That is the source of the error message.

Comment: Then which is the domain of `fx`? The problem arises with respect to the domain of `fx` not `F`!

Comment: @jheidk51 `fx` has no valid domain, because `xx[r]>1` for `1>r>0`.

Comment: Then how can one get an `fx` such that `FF[r] = fx[xx[r]]` for any `r` within the domain of `x[r]` and `F[r]`. Note that `x` increases monotoncally with `r` so such an `fx` mathematically exists.

Comment: Do you see my point?

Comment: Are you asking then for `FF[r[xx]]` with no loss of precision?

Comment: Exactly! (of course a different notation should be used in the code since `FF` and `xx` are already in use but you see what I mean)

Comment: @kglr What is the function behind `@*` in your comment? Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  Composition

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks, searching for   @*  doesn|t work.

Comment: As observed in the comments, you need to invert `xx[r]`. Since `xx'[0] == 0`, this won't be possible without a loss of accuracy locally. It shouldn't be a big drawback (unless `r == 0+` is especially important to you), but it is a technical difficulty. The bigger problem is that the highly accurate interpolants are stored as a piecewise sequence of degree-9 polynomials in Chebyshev series form. There's no easy way to invert this for `xx`. Doing it is not hard but it would take some coding and time to do. I've used `chebInterpolation` (search this site) for similar work.

Comment: Another approach would be to use `FindRoot` to invert `xx[r]` to the desire degree of precision. You should get good starting points from `rApprox = Interpolation[Transpose@{xx["ValuesOnGrid"], Flatten@xx["Grid"]}]`. (From @bbgodfrey's answer, it seems you might have to delete some duplicate points.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
fx = Interpolation[Transpose[{xx["ValuesOnGrid"], FF["ValuesOnGrid"]}][[24 ;;]],
    InterpolationOrder -> 15]
```

provides `FF[r[xx]]` without loss of precision.  The first 23 elements are dropped, because the first 24 are identical in `xx`.  Here is what the function looks like.

```
Plot[fx[x], {x, 1.1, 1.435}, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Black, Bold}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

Motivated by comments below by MichaelE2, I plotted the actual accuracy of `fx` for increasing values of `InterpolationOrder`.  At 15, the computed accuracy is substantially better than the requested 30 digits

```
ParametricPlot[{xx[r], RealExponent[fx[xx[r]] - FF[r]]}, {r, 0, 1}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 100, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Black, Bold}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, AxesLabel -> {"xx", "fx"}]
```

[image]

except for `xx` less than about 1.100021410.  Higher `InterpolationOrder`can reduce but not eliminate this small domain of poor accuracy, because `r'[xx]` is singular at `x = 1.1`.

Comment: Counting the points that are identical in `x` has to be done manually?

Comment: @jheidk51 No. The first time I ran `Interpolation`, it told me that `1.1``100` was duplicated, so I ran `Position` to find the duplicates.  They were the first 24.  I also could have used `Union` which might have been better.

Comment: Thanks a lot! An extra question: How can I use this method to get `r[x]`?

Comment: @jheidk51  Yes, you can.  By the way, my suggestion just above to try `Union` is not a good idea.

Comment: @jheidk51  Specifically, see how I inverted a complicated function in `a[s]` to generate `int` in question [211194](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/211553/1063).

Comment: I don’t know if I will have time to get back to this but the method here agrees with the original FF[r] only to about 13 digits on average. Not why the OP emphasized 30 digits in the question.

Comment: @MichaelE2  What basis did you use for the comparison?  `fx[xx[r]] == FF[r]`?  The match is perfect at grid points, as one would expect.  Between grid points, differences in overall interpolation are bound to create discrepancies, I believe.  However, the claimed accuracy of `FF` and `xx` may only hold at grid points anyway.  What are your thoughts?

Comment: They should match at the grid points because of the way they are defined. It's in the interpolation error between the grid points where the difference lays. (`NDSolve` returns an order-9 interpolant and your method returns an order-3 one.) I used `Plot[fx[xx[r]] - FF[r] // RealExponent, {r, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]` and eyeballed the "average." When I used `NIntegrate` to compute the $L^2$ norm $\left(\int_0^1 [f(x(r)) - F(r)]^2 \,dx\right)^{1/2}$, it came out a bit over $10^{-10}$. Does that seem the right approach?

Comment: @MichaelE2  I increased the interpolation order of `fx` to 9 and obtained a typical `Plot` accuracy of about 10^-28, except very near `r = 0`, again  by eyeball.  I shall modify my answer accordingly.  I must say that so large an improvement surprised me, because `FF[r]` involves a single order-9 interpolation, while `fx[xx[r]]` now involves the convolution in some sense of two order-9 interpolations.  In any case, thank you for looking into the accuracy of my answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Increasing the interpolation order of `fx` to 15 further reduces the typical `Plot` accuracy to -38, which seems strange to me.  Further, increasing the interpolation to 30 produces no increased improvement except very near `r = 0`.

Comment: Neat. Actually, I didn't think of raising the `InterpolatingOrder` on the existing grid & values of `xx` and `FF`. It's not as accurate (theoretically) as the method I outlined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211760/how-to-combine-ndsolve-interpolating-functions#comment542612_211760), but I'm surprised how good it is. -- 2nd comment: Cool! That corresponds to the Chebyshev series I see in `xx` and `FF`.  (To see a typical one, execute `FF[[4, 1000]]`.) The error is roughly the last term in a rapidly convergent series such as they have.

Comment: Basically `NDSolve` is way too conservative in its step size choices, and we get a more accurate solution than requested.

Comment: Actually, I think my reaction to the "2nd comment" was hasty. It doesn't quite make sense to me, what I said (or what I was thinking at least). It is correct what I said about the convergence, but I don't see how it's connected to raising the interpolation order, at least not as directly as I was thinking.